# angular variables in youtube iframe call

Tags: angularjs, iframe, youtube

My code lets people select youtube videos to show. The code is written in angular and I simply want to populate the iframe components with the angular variables. Here are some of the things I have tried and none of them work.

Produces Error

```
<div>
    <iframe width="{{obj.content.videoWidth}}" 
            height="{{obj.content.videoHeight}}" 
            ng-src="{{obj.content.url}}" 
            frameborder="0" 
            allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>    
</div>
```

Does nothing

```
<div>
    <iframe width="{{obj.content.videoWidth}}" 
            height="{{obj.content.videoHeight}}" 
            ng-src="obj.content.url" 
            frameborder="0" 
            allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>    
</div>
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: This code only tells a little bit of the story.   What does your controller look like?   What is the error?    Are you sure those values are present?

Comment: Also, you want the mustaches in the 2nd code block for ng-source.   `obj.content.url` would be interpreted as a literal string.

Comment: Sorry, the controller does contain the correct data. Give me a few minutes and I will put out what that content is.